# Getting (X,Y) projected coordinates of point instead of its longitude and latitude in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I am reading a shapefile through ArcPy. The shapefile has both geographical coordinate system and projected coordinate system. When I try to get the coordinates of a point geometry in the shapefile, the  result is always the point's longitude and latitude.

How could I get its projected coordinates?

The code are as follow:

```
        sr = arcpy.Describe(shp).spatialReference
        print (sr.name)
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, ["SHAPE@"])as lines:
            for line in lines:
                s = line[0].getPart(0)
                for p in s:
                    print(p.X)
```

the output:

```
WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_18N
-72.5049105
-72.505729
-72.5058427
...
```

It looks the shapefile has a projected coordinate system. I am wondering why the points are still recorded with its longitude and latitude.

Comment: A shapefile can only have one coordinate system.. are you saying the shapefile *could* be either geographic or projected? If you're getting geographic coordinates then the shapefile must be defined as geographic.To get your coordinates as a projected coordinate system create a spatial reference (SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(EPSG_CODE)) then the geometry .projectAs(SR).. to be any more helpful I would need to see the code where you're reading the geometries.

Comment: Thank you  all very much. I have posted the code and output.

Comment: After for line in lines: and before s = line[0].getPart(0) is where you want to line.projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(EPSG_Code)) and the part 0 will be returned in the spatial reference given by EPSG_Code, which spatial reference you use depends on where your data is, I would suggest WGS84 UTM might be a good choice but you need to find what zone and hemisphere suits you.

Comment: Your original coordinates are obviously in GCS, while the shapefile's coordinate system has been defined as PCS.  I'd suggest re-defining the spatial reference as GCS, and then reproject the shapefile to PCS.

Comment: Thank you all. Barbarossa is right. It has been solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use projectAs method of the [PointGeometry class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/pointgeometry.htm):

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("points_wgs84","SHAPE@") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0].projectAs(arcpy.SpatialReference(3006)).centroid
```

Output:

```
667780,048763737 6580256,91702263 NaN NaN
667766,158110956 6580270,80767541 NaN NaN
667796,585255144 6580264,19307885 NaN NaN
```